# With Grep create new JSON object from JSON object based on a grep or delete function

Tags: jquery, json

Given following JSON object

```
var data = {
    "ok" : true,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "type" : "message",
            "subtype" : "bot_remove"
        },
        {
            "type":"message",
            "subtype":"file_share",
            "file" : {
                "name" : "file_name"
            },
        }    
    ],
    "has_more" : false
}
```

using jQuery I'de like to create a new JSON object that contains only the object with the value `"file_share"`. Im just not sure if I should be using `$.grep` or javascript's delete

something like

```
var newObject = [];
var result = $.grep(data.messages , function(key,value){
    return +key.subtype !== "file_share";
    newObject.push(result)
});
```

or using `$.grep` to filter the object whose length more than 0 (as the second object contains a child object).

Would I then have to `stringify` and / or `$.parseJSON()` the `newObject`?

Comment: JSON is just a serialisation format, there's no such thing as a "JSON object"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var result = data.messages.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.subtype === 'file_share';
});

if (result.length) {
    // item found, use `result[0]` to access it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Alnitak, much appreciated. Can you explain if(result.length){}

Comment: The `if (result.length)` is there to ensure that the required object is actually found.  You need `result[0]` but if the element doesn't exist the code would generate `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to access the file object. Something like $.each(result.file , function(){$('#ul').append('<li>'+this.name+'</li>') }) ?

Comment: given only one matching object (your question strongly implied singular, not plural), there's no need for a `.each` - just use `result[0].file.name`

Comment: I think i did it but please check if you have a second:

Comment: var printList = $.each(result , function(i){
  console.log(result[i].file.title)
})

Comment: `$.each` doesn't return a value, and your `file` sub-object doesn't contain a `title` key

Comment: Completely understand. I'd hoped to keep the amount of code I used to a minimum, but the api I'm using call in a number of objects with the same structure. Should I there fore use the $.each – it seems to work? Sorry for the obfuscation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100613/discussion-between-james-and-alnitak).

Answer (score 1):

You should look a little more carefully at how JQuery grep works here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

The usage should look like this:

```
var result = $.grep(data.messages, function(message){
    return message.subtype == 'file_share';
});
```

This will return a copy of messages filtered like you want. The returned objects will not be Deep Copies though, so altering them will alter the original object.

You can see how to create a deep copy of result here: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)